# Explaining the polymer designer code - The simple file system

Tags: html, polymer

I have been working on polymer/designer off late. I wanted to mess around, add more components etc. I am still learning polymer and I need some help.

I need to know the difference between the components and the elements. I know what components are.

Clone this: https://github.com/Polymer/designer

Run it locally. I need to understand how the code works for this. Check the components and the  elements folders. And also the index file. A simple explanation is to how it is all connected and rendered etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it components are the building blocks for elements. As you can see in the elements folder you need at least one component for your element. In general I think the term might be interchangeable since components have dependencies on other components as well so they are actually elements as well. I think you should worry too much about the terminology :)